# How to embed a cocoa app in another cocoa app and launch it as a subprocess

Tags: swift, macos, cocoa, macos-mojave

I want to embed a  App A in another App B. When App A is launched it should act as a wrapper and internally launch App B without showing App B in docbar.Purpose of App A is just a wrapper ,it should do some initialisation to launch App B depending from where it is getting launched

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your project, build both apps using separate targets.

In App A > Target > Build Phases:

- Add App B to the `Target Dependancies`
- Add the product of App B to the `Copy Bundle Resources` phase.

Now when you build App A, Xcode will build App B and copy the finished App B into the `Resources` folder of App A's bundle.

You don't explain *why* you want to do this, so here are some ideas to get you started...

Option A:

Use the `NSBundle` class to locate the embedded App B and launch it however you see fit (directly, using `launchd`, etc.).

If you don't want App B to show up in the dock or have a menu bar, you need to set the `LSUIPresentationMode` in the app's `Info.plist` or adjust the app's `activationPolicy` property programatically.

Option B:

Consider creating an XPC Service. An XPC services is a special embedded executable that macOS will launch for you whenever you need it and set up an XPC connection for you so you can talk to it and do work.

See [Creating XPC Services](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/MacOSX/Conceptual/BPSystemStartup/Chapters/CreatingXPCServices.html)

XPC also has facilities so that a faceless (non-app) helper process can have a UI that appears in your app. (This is the way Safari works; each page is handled by a separate helper process, using XPC to control the page and present it in a Safari window.)